# Python count list and types

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

In python I have the following list:

```
['personA', 'banana']
['personB', 'banana']
['personA', 'grape']
['personA', 'lemon']
['personA', 'lemon']
['personB', 'banana']
```

How do I get a list in the following form:

```
['personA', 'lemon', 2 ]
['personB', 'banana', 2]
```

I have to count how many times the fruit occurs for a person. 
*(I have generalised my question with fruit)*
For those who downvoted: I can understand the frustration if I did something wrong when posting. I'm a new member, so if you downvote, please mention what bugged you so I can take that in mind for my next questions.

Comment: So how would you go about this if you did this on paper? Can you work out how to translate that to code yourself?

Comment: What happened to grape for personA in your output? Do you only want the most common fruit?

Comment: Please include in your question what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newlist = []
for sublist in yourlist:
    already_in_list = False
    for index, newsublist in enumerate(newlist):
        if sublist == newsublist[:-1]:
            newlist[index][2] += 1
            already_in_list = True
    if not already_in_list:
        newlist.append(sublist+[1])
```

-

```
>>>newlist
[['personA', 'banana', 1], ['personB', 'banana', 2], ['personA', 'grape', 1], ['personA', 'lemon', 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use `collections.Counter`, you could use the list's `count` method though

```
your_list = [['personA', 'banana'], ['personB', 'banana'], ['personA', 'grape'], ['personA', 'lemon'], ['personA', 'lemon'], ['personB', 'banana']]

for i in your_list:
    print(i, your_list.count(i))
```